# How to translate computer/software logging?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would I best translate logging of data by a computer program?

- A log
- Logging to a file
- A log entry

We also ‘book’ entries to a log file, such an entry is called:

- A log booking

For now we have just chosen *Log* (and *Logbuchung* for that last one), but I only know *Buchung* as a flight, hotel booking (like *Reservierung*).

---

Update, following up on a comment under O.R.Mapper’s [answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26690/10963).
I am not happy with that term *log booking* in our source language. That’s why I mention it separately. I may suggest that we remove that, and maybe use *log entry* there as well.

Comment: Logging is also common in German, but a German word would be Anmeldung

Comment: Anmeldung is for "logging in", but definitely *not* for creating log file entries.

Comment: the log --dt.--> "das Logging"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The English word *Log* will be understood, as explained in the [other answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26689/5999). It is related (and obviously similar) to the German word [*Logbuch*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Logbuch), which denotes logs or diaries aboard ships and some other vehicles (such as aircraft or spaceships), as well as some logs in contexts that might be metaphorically related to the aforementioned ship context<sup>1</sup>. However, *Log* itself does not seem to have been used in the sense of the English *log* in German before being introduced via IT contexts; Google NGram shows a certain rise in frequency of the term *Log* in German texts starting between 1990 and 2000, and at least random samples look like after 2000, quite some books mention *Log* related to software logs, whereas before 1990, books seem to almost exclusively refer to logarithms when they write *Log*.

However, the actual German translation of *log* would be **Protokoll**. It is a rather frequently used word that appears in many contexts in German (*Protokolle* are created on business meetings, on meetings between parents and schoolteachers, on organized meetings (to make decisions) between tenants of a house, during court trials, etc.), so every native speaker will likely know it. Some examples of real-world IT-related usage:

- The German version of [Windows Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) routinely uses this term to refer to logging:

[image: German translation of Windows Event Viewer using the term *Protokoll*]

- Accordingly, a system log viewer in Ubuntu is titled [*Systemprotokoll*](http://www.computerwissen.de/uploads/pics/Analysieren_Sie_bei_System-Stoerungen_die_Logdateien_Ihres_Linux-Systems.jpg) in the German version.
- "Die Direktive `ErrorLog` bestimmt den Namen der Datei, in welcher der Server alle auftretenden Fehler protokolliert werden. Wenn *Dateiname* nicht absolut ist, wird er relativ zu `ServerRoot` betrachtet. (...) Die Information wird im Zugriffsprotokoll festgehalten." from the [Apache web server documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/de/mod/core.html), many other occurrences in that document
- The [WikiBook on Java programming](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Standard:_Logging_API_von_Java) explains to German-speaking programmers what *logging* means: "Mit Logging wird das Protokollieren eines Programmablaufes beschrieben"
- A [thread on a Java forum](http://www.java-forum.org/thema/log4j-protokollierung-auf-die-gui-zaubern.18352/) related to the [log4j logging library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) shows both words (*Protokoll* and *Log*, according to different preferences of writers).
- A [programming tutorial on logging in VB.NET and C#](http://www.it-visions.de/lserver/CodeSampleDetails.aspx?c=2800), titled "Schreiben einer Protokolldatei"
- [Log files created during Windows setup](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd744583%28v=ws.10%29.aspx): "Windows Setup-Protokolldateien"

Based upon that word, the expressions you asked about are:

- A log: ein Protokoll
- Logging to a file: [den Ablauf/die Ausführung/…] in einer Datei protokollieren
- A log entry: ein Protokolleintrag; ein Eintrag/eine Zeile/… im Protokoll

Concerning the expression with booking, I am not quite sure — does that mean you call the act of logging something “booking an entry into a log”? In that case, I would still use *protokollieren* in German.

Alternatively, do you mean that a booking (of something else) is getting logged? In that case, *log booking* seems like a misnomer to start with, as it should be either a *logged booking*, or a *booking [in a] log*, i.e. something like *Buchungsprotokoll* (if the whole log only contains bookings), or *protokollierte Buchung* (for a single event).

<sup>1</sup>: This contextual restriction of where a *Logbuch* would be used is also illustrated in older text samples provided by [userunknown](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/266/user-unknown):

- Reise nach dem Vorgebirge der guten Hoffnung, ..., Andreas Sparrmann, Berlin 1784: "Da ausser mir nur sehr wenige Personen von der Wache auf dem Verdeck waren, wurde dieser Vorfall weder in das Logbuch, noch in eins von den bereits gedruckten Tagebüchern eingetragen" (the protagonist is travelling on a ship, hence there is a *Logbuch*)
- Reisen eines Officiers durch die Schweiz und Italien, Hannover, 1786, "Er schreibet auch auf eine schwarze Tafel den Lauf, Wind, und die Anmerkungen, welches alle 24 Stunden ins Logbuch oder Schifsjüurnal getragen wird." (a letter describing the operations aboard a ship)
- Reisebeschr. nach Arabien u a umliegenden Ländern, Carsten Niebuhr, 1774, ‎"Da ich bemerkte, daß unsere Rechnung nach dem Logbuch uns bey unsere Ausreise weiter nördlich und bey unserer Zurückkunft weiter südlich brachte als wir wirklich waren (...)" (this, again, describes a journey aboard a ship)

(Of course, this does not mean the word can absolutely never appear in another context; almost every word can be used in any context and meaning, given the appropriate metaphor. However, such occurrences do not seem to be relevant when looking at the *typical* usage of a word.)

Comment: [Können wir bitte diese endlos lange Kommentarliste auf das Wesentliche reduzieren, d.h. mit einem Edit in die Antwort verpacken? Wer soll denn das alles lesen?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/431/why-should-i-edit-or-answer-rather-than-comment)

Comment: @Takkat: Ich habe die belegbaren Informationen aus der Diskussion in meine Antwort eingearbeitet; sollte es daran begründete Zweifel geben, so denke ich, dass eine separate Antwort geeigneter ist, um eine andere Meinung vorzubringen, als in einer Antwort mehrere alternative Meinungen unterzubringen.

Comment: Ich bitte darum den Kommentar nicht zu entfernen, dass man für die Fachwelt nicht nachträglich versuchen soll Übersetzungen für dominierende Begriffe zu etablieren, die nur zu Unverständnis und Verwechslungen führen wie hier im Fall "Protokoll". Andererseits reicht solch eine Übersetzung wie "Protokoll" auch nicht aus, um dem Laien in einem Wort klar zu machen, worum es sich nun genau handelt. Es übersetzt auch keiner Smartphone mit Klugtelefon.

Answer (score 8):

*Logdatei* is quite common in German, even *Logfile* is not unusual around computers. (Note the capital "L" for a noun in German)
*Logbuch* is a bit more reserved. You would expect that on a ship or aircraft, but not in a piece of software.

For the creation of a log entry you can use *loggen* and a single entry in the log file is a *Logeintrag*.

If you want something more formal, less computer-oriented, the term *Aufzeichnung* comes to mind.

If for example you wanted to say *we are logging all user transactions in a log file*, you could (apart from using the term *logging*, which would be accepted) say: *Wir speichern alle Benutzertransaktionen in einer Datei / Logdatei*.

Comment: Burki hat recht. Log ist Computer-Fachsprache und es gibt keine dt. Übersetzung. Für den Laien kann man das höchstens mit "interne Aufzeichnung von technischen Detailinformationen" beschreiben.

Comment: @falkb: "Log" und davon abgeleitete Wörter werden zwar häufig verwendet, aber natürlich gibt es eine gängige deutsche Übersetzung, die auch im IT-Bereich immer wieder verwendet wird und Benutzern verständlich ist: Protokoll/Protokollierung/protokollieren ([Beispiel](http://techfrage.de/question/174/windows-8-ereignisanzeige-aufrufen-ereignisprotokolle/)).

Comment: By the way, it should be noted that the question speaks about "Logbuchung", while this answer mentions "Logbuch". "Buchung" and "Buch" are two quite different concepts (just like "booking" and "book").

Comment: @O.R.Mapper i was assuming he meant *Logbuch*, but you are right, this assumption could have been wrong

Comment: @Burki. The assumption is wrong, sorry for the confusion. Updated my question.

Comment: @JanDoggen so by *log booking* you mean the act of writing a log entry to a log file?

Comment: @Burki, yes but it is a 'special' kind of entry which you could interpret as a booking.

Comment: @JanDoggen could you explain that? I don't think i really understand what you mean